# How can I know which button was clicked in the notification?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am developing an application, I have 2 buttons in an on the notification. How can I know which button the user has clicked?

This my Notification codes;

```
public void  NotificationSettings(Context context){
        Intent stateIntent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        stateIntent.putExtra("id", 100);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, stateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "access2020")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24)
                .setContentTitle("Academy Notification")
                .setContentText("Hey this is an important notifications")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24, "Set Active", pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24,"Dismiss", pendingIntent);

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    }
```

and My Broadcast

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this way but still i am not sure it is the right way

```
public void  NotificationSettings(Context context){
        Intent stateIntent0 = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        Intent stateIntent1 = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);


        stateIntent0.putExtra("id", 100);
        stateIntent1.putExtra("id", 200);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, stateIntent0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, stateIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "lemubitA")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24)
                .setContentTitle("Lemubit Academy Notification")
                .setContentText("Hey this is an important notifications")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24, "Set Active", pendingIntent0)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24,"Dismiss", pendingIntent1);

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    }
```

AND this my Broadcast

```
int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, notificationId+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an identifier to the intent as an extra and then retrieve in your BroadcastReceiver.

```java
public void  NotificationSettings(Context context){
        // put an extra identifier for Set Active Action
        Intent setActiveStateIntent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        setActiveStateIntent.putExtra("id", 100);
        setActiveStateIntent.putExtra("action", "Action.SetActive");
        PendingIntent setActivePendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, setActiveStateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // put an extra identifier for Dismiss
        Intent dismissStateIntent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        dismissStateIntent.putExtra("id", 100);
        dismissStateIntent.putExtra("action", "Action.Dismiss");
        PendingIntent dismissPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, dismissStateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "access2020")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24)
                .setContentTitle("Academy Notification")
                .setContentText("Hey this is an important notifications")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24, "Set Active", setActivePendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_alert_24,"Dismiss", dismissPendingIntent);

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
}
```

Then in your BroadcastReceiver you can do the following:

```java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("Action.Dismiss")) {
             // perform your dismiss action
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("Action.SetActive")) {
            // perform your set active logic
        } else {
           // handle invalid action
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Thank you but addAction method is taking pendingintent, you wrote Intent. Can you check it? Meanwhile you can check my answer maybe it is right way (it is below)

Comment: Actually still not working correctly. Maybe you can check my answer.

Comment: @BurhanYaprak What doesn't work? Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Whichever button I click, the first button works (works this "if" every click: if (intent.getStringExtra ("action"). Equals ("Action.Dismiss")) { ).

Comment: Now i changed  request code ( it was 0, now 1) for second pending intent and now it is working. Can you check it? (this one : PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, dismissStateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); )